# Google App Engine Java - Indexes and Keys

Tags: java, google-app-engine, indexing

There is some restriction to add keys to the datastore-indexes?

I have Test.java

```
@EntityBean(entityGroup="TestRoot", entityGroupKeyName="TestList")
public class Test implements Serializable, JSONConvertible {
    @Property(key=true,indexable=true)
    private String keyName;
    @Property(indexable=true)
    private String userCode;
    @Property(indexable=true)
    private String name;
...
```

And in my datastore-indexes.xml:

```
<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true">
    <property name="keyName" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>

<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="keyName" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>

<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true">
    <property name="userCode" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>

<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="userCode" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>

<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true">
    <property name="name" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>

<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true" source="manual">
    <property name="name" direction="asc"/>
</datastore-index>
```

I have all my indexes in serving status

When I order my Test List works fine with "userCode" and "name" but with "keyName" doesn't, any help?

Comment: How are you using @EntityBean with Datastore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about [Key Filters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Key_Filters). By default GAE already has an ascending index on keys, so no need to build one. For descending index on keys try this:

```
<datastore-index kind="Flight" ancestor="true">
    <property name="__key__" direction="desc"/>
</datastore-index>
```